# Google Cloud Function deploy error: provided function is not a loadable module

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to build my GCF project with Typescript from the ground up. My goal with this project (and this question) is to understand how cloud functions work and to perform all the setup steps manually, so that's why I'm not copying any sample code or using an automated tool.

First, here's my `src/index.ts` file:

```
export const helloWorld = (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.send('Hello, world 4');
}
```

After I run typescript compiler, I get this `dist/index.js` file, which seems perfectly reasonable:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.helloWorld = function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello, world 4');
};
```

My `package.json` is set up to point to this file:

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx tsc-watch --onSuccess 'npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=helloWorld'",
    "deploy": "gcloud functions deploy helloWorld --runtime nodejs10 --trigger-http"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^1.1.2",
    "tsc-watch": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

I wanted to setup local testing environment first, so I used [functions framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs). When I run it, it all works perfectly:

```
$ npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=helloWorld
Serving function...
Function: helloWorld
URL: http://localhost:8080/
```

However, when I try to deploy, I get this error:

```
$ gcloud functions deploy helloWorld --runtime nodejs10 --trigger-http
Created .gcloudignore file. See `gcloud topic gcloudignore` for details.
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Provided code is not a loadable module.
Could not load the function, shutting down.
```

Why does it say that my `index.js` is not a loadable module and how can I fix this error?

---

**Update**

Turns out the `gcloud` doesn't respect `package.json`'s `main` field. When I specified that it should take `dist` folder explicitly with the `--source` flag, it deployed the file:

```
gcloud functions deploy helloWorld --source=dist/ --runtime nodejs10 --trigger-http
```

However, it still doesn't work because it seems to assume that **everything**, including package.json, is contained in this directory - so it doesn't link any of the library dependencies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out, `.gitignore` by default is imported in GCF's `.gcloudignore` file, and since I ignore js files in my `.gitignore`, they never make it to GCF.

To fix it, just remove this line:

```
#!include:.gitignore
```

I have also created a [small template project](https://github.com/golergka/gcf-typescript-template/) for using Typescript with GCF.

Answer (score 5):

**Add `!/dist` after `#!include:.gitignore` in your `.gcloudignore` file.**

In my opinion, it's better to leave the `#!include:.gitnore` line in your `.gcloudignore` file, so that when people add something to `.gitignore`, it will be automatically included in the `.gcloudignore`, too.

For files and directories where you want them to be ignored by `git` but not by `gcloud`, I would add them explicitly in the `.gcloudignore` file.

Let's take my example, where I have a TypeScript project. I don't want the output of `tsc` to be version-controlled, but I do want those files to include for `gcloud` for obvious reasons: the files in the `built` (or `dist`) folder is actually my function (app).

```
### .gitignore
node_modules
built

### .gcloudignore file's content
#!include:.gitignore
# Do not ignore built (or dist) folder for gcloud:
!/built
!/dist
```

I prefer this solution because, by default, the ignored files from git are also ignored by gcloud, so I don't need to worry that people forget that we have multiple ignore files.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error, only locally.  The build directory turned out to be missing because I forgot to make it first.  In IntelliJ, I usually add that as a "Before launch" command in Configurations.

Comment: Okay, that's funny.  Here I am 6 months later and I just solved my own problem.  Thanks past self!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error because I have my function code in a sub directory that I didn't specify when I ran the functions-framework command.

`npx functions-framework --target=imageUpdate --signature_type=cloudevent --source=functions`

```
my_project_root/
├── functions/
│   ├── index.js
├── package.json
```

index.js:

```
functions.cloudEvent('imageUpdate', async event=>{/*...*/});
```

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs#configure-the-functions-framework